# React props id is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a question. I am trying to create chat app using Scaledrone but I get an error message when I try to run it in the browser. The chat loads, but when I type a message and press enter, I receive an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
Messages.renderMessage
  17 | renderMessage(message, index) {
  18 |   const { member, text, time } = message;
  19 |   const { currentMember } = this.props;
> 20 |   const messageFromMe = member.id === currentMember.id;
     | ^  21 |   const className = messageFromMe ? "messages currentMember" : "messages";
  22 |   return (
  23 |     <li key={index} className={className}>
```

I am not sure if I did something wrong in the Scaledrone settings in App.js or is it some kind of props error.

My code is down below:

I would appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: `currentUser={this.state.member}` needs to be `currentMember={this.state.member}` You are passing it as `currentUser` but inside the Messages component you are looking into props for `currentMember`

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
<Messages
    messages={this.state.messages}
    currentUser={this.state.member} // <--- you are passing currentUser
/>

// so as a result you wont get `currentMember` inside `Messages.js`
```

To :

```
<Messages
    messages={this.state.messages}
    currentMember ={this.state.member} // <--- should be currentMember 
/>
```

---

And also

```
state = {
    messages: [],
    member: {
      id : "" , // <---- here there should be some initial state value
      username: randomName(),
      color: randomColor(),
    },
 };
```

Comment: Omg, cannot believe I didn´t see that. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please, be attentive, you set property `currentUser` calling Messages from App, but read `currentMember`, which is not set, so the mistake pops

```
currentUser={this.state.member}
```